# Unable to start and connect 3 docker services - Redis, Python 3.7 Slim (Running DRF) and Celery

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, redis, docker-compose, celery

I am trying to containerise my application which is developed using technologise like DRF, Celery and Redis (as a broker).

I want to prepare `docker-compose` which will start all the three services (DRF, Celery and Redis (as a broker).

I also want to prepare the `Dockerfile.prod` for deloyment.

Here is what I have done so far -

```
version: "3"

services:

  redis:
    container_name: Redis-Container
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
    command: "redis-server"
      

  dropoff-backend:
    container_name: Dropoff-Backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/logistics_backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
        - "8080"
    restart: always
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"
    links: 
      - redis
    depends_on: 
      - redis
      # - celery
  
  celery:
    container_name: celery-container
    build: .
    command: "celery -A logistics_project worker -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - redis
```

**Dockerfile**(Not for deployment)

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
# FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc  -y &&\
    mkdir /logistics_backend

WORKDIR /logistics_backend

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY . /logistics_backend

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -U "celery[redis]"

RUN python manage.py makemigrations &&\
    python manage.py migrate

RUN python manage.py loaddata roles businesses route_status route_type order_status service_city payment_status

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:80"]
```

The problem with the existing `docker-compose` is it returns the error as stated below -

```
celery-container   | [2020-10-08 16:59:25,843: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
celery-container   | Trying again in 32.00 seconds... (16/100)
```

In **Setting.py** I have defined this for `radis` connection

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600} 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
```

I don't know how should I extend my `Dockerfile` which is current used for the development, to form a `Dockerfile.prod` which could be deployable.

All of my three containers are working -

[image]

Comment: How are you configuring the location of the Redis server?  (Or of a relational database?)

Comment: For database I am using a cloud instance and for redis I have will update the code. Please have look.

Comment: In Docker, `localhost` is "this container": you're telling Celery to make a Redis connection to the Celery container.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the overall networking environment and how to connect between containers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your REDIS_HOST in your Setting.py to be “redis” instead of “localhost”.